# Replace a word which contains a $ character in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm having issues replacing a tag within a message where the tag begins with a $ character.

Here's the code I'm trying to use:

```
$tag = '$TAG';
$message = '..text $TAGd d$TAG $TAG text..';
$pattern = '/\b\\'.$tag.'\b/';
echo $pattern."<br/>";
echo preg_replace($pattern, "REPLACED", $message);
```

output:

```
/\b\$TAG\b/
..text $TAGd dREPLACED $TAG text..
```

I want it to replace the last occurance of $TAG since it's the only one not obstructed by additional characters. However it keeps replacing the 2nd one no matter what I try.

Some variations that I've tried:
Skipping the $tag variable string concatination

```
$message = '..text $TAGd d$TAG $TAG text..';
$pattern = '/\b\$TAG\b/';
echo $pattern."<br/>";
echo preg_replace($pattern, "REPLACED", $message);
```

output:

```
/\b\$TAG\b/
..text $TAGd dREPLACED $TAG text..
```

Removing the backslash before $

```
$message = '..text $TAGd d$TAG $TAG text..';
$pattern = '/\b$TAG\b/';
echo $pattern."<br/>";
echo preg_replace($pattern, "REPLACED", $message);
```

output:

```
/\b\$TAG\b/
..text $TAGd d$TAG $TAG text..
```

Adding a second backslash before $

```
$message = '..text $TAGd d$TAG $TAG text..';
$pattern = '/\b\\$TAG\b/';
echo $pattern."<br/>";
echo preg_replace($pattern, "REPLACED", $message);
```

output:

```
/\b\$TAG\b/
..text $TAGd dREPLACED $TAG text..
```

Any help regarding this issue will be much appreciated, since I don't seem able to wrap my mind around what I'm doing wrong. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\B` for beginning of word and `\b` for end of word:

```
$tag = '$TAG';
$message = '..text $TAGd d$TAG $TAG text..';
$pattern = '/\B\\'.$tag.'\b/';
echo $pattern."<br/>";
echo preg_replace($pattern, "REPLACED", $message);
```

worked fine for me.  I'm not sure why this is the case, as normally it should be just `\b` - but it did solve the issue.

Comment: That's strange... \B is "not a word boundary", isn't it? I'm confused :D

Comment: `\B` works because `$` is not a word character. In this case it would mean `(?<!\w)` (which is equivalent to `(?<=\W|^)`.

Comment: See the comment above, `\B` is `(?<!\W)(?!\W)|(?<!\w)(?!\w)`, which in this case boils down to just `(?<!\w)`.

Comment: @Qtax thanks! I struggled to explain why it worked.  I know `\B` is not really a word boundary, so was rather going with "It works, "why" is not as important"

Comment: Thanks Qtax. Your comment wasn't up when I posted my mine.

Comment: I found this to be the easiest solution to my problem.
Thank you so much :)
And Thank you Qtax for the explanation as to why it works.

Answer (score 1):

Replace dollar signs ($) with dollar sign backslash zero ($\0)

http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/preg-replace-problem-with-dollar-signs-35089.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to use other anchor instead of `\b`, as it matches positions between word `\w` and non-word `\W` charters (`$` is not a word character).

Maybe you wan't an expression more like:

```
'/(?<!\w)' . $tag . '\b/'
```

But it depends on when you want it to match.